# Role Based Flutter application using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working on a college project named event-management flutter app. Need to have role-based authentication.

Different Roles Needed Are:

1. User
2. Student Coordinator
3. Event Coordinator
4. Principal
5. HOD
6. LabIncharge

I have created boolean values for different roles.

```
    bool admin = false;
    bool eCoordinator = false;
    bool labIncharge = false;
    bool principal = false;
    bool hod = false;
    bool sCoordinator = false;
```

User Data will have field which will specify the role:

```
usersReference.document(gCurrentUser.id).setData({
        "id": gCurrentUser.id,
        "profileName": gCurrentUser.displayName,
        "username": username,
        "url": gCurrentUser.photoUrl,
        "email": gCurrentUser.email,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "admin": admin,
        "hod": hod,
        "labIncharge": labIncharge,
        "principal": principal,
        "eCoordinator": eCoordinator,
        "sCoordinator": sCoordinator,
      });
```

How it look in cloud firestore:

[image]

**How do I get data and update roles by changing the boolean from firebase?**

Comment: You may be interested by https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: I understand this isn't an answer, but have you considered a more efficient way of tracking the roles using and `enum`? For your case, create the enum by `enum Role { admin, eCoordinator, labIncharge, principal, hod, sCoordinator }` and then track the role in a field of your user class - `Role role` or (if you need to track more than one) `List<Role> roles`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to create an accessible function that can be called to update all the information of a given user (I wouldn't recommend this if your document is massive though).

```dart
Future<void> updateUser(User userData) async {
    // CollectionReference get _usersCollection => _firestore.collection('USERS');
    DocumentReference docRef =
        _usersCollection.document(userData.firebaseUser.uid);
    Map<String, dynamic> userJson = userData.toJson();
    await docRef.setData(userJson, merge: true);

  }
}
```

Your use case may change a bit based on your class structure and how you wan to use it, but the core of this solution is at:

```dart
await docRef.setData(userJson, merge: true);
```

Where you can write over any changed data into Firestore.